# how can i do to hide iframe in ie 6,7,8? setting attribute of style = "display:none" does not work!

Tags: iframe, cross-browser, hide

how can hide iframe in ie 6,7,8? setting attribute of style = "display:none" does not work!

sorry, i foreget to post the context.

The iframe is dynamic generated by javascript.such as :

```
  function addIframe(node) {  
      var iframe = document.createElement("div");  
      iframe.src = ****;  
      iframe.style = "display:none";   
      node.appendChild(iframe);   
}
```

the hidden frame generated by function above works in firefox and chrome but fails in ie.

Comment: for me `style="display: none;"` works, but it rather gives a javascript-exception `access is denied`

Comment: Use `iframe.style.cssText = 'display:none;`, or even better, `iframe.style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 2):

#### Target IE8 Only

```
iframe { //display:none }
```

#### Target IE7, IE6

```
iframe { *display:none }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Try `display:none !important`. Otherwise, try ugly hack

```
border:none;
width:1px;
height:1px;
visibility:hidden
```

Comment: Other hack would be to give it an absolute position and something like top:-5000px

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving it off-screen. Be careful with something like this as there may be security implications from trying to hide an iframe.

```
.some-selector {
  margin-left: -2000px;
  position: absolute;
}
```